# Using OCCI - create connection

Tags: c++, oracle, connection, occi

Is there anyone using OCCI library for work with Oracle database?
I'm trying to connect from Visual Studio 2017 project

```
Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
Connection *con;
con = env->createConnection(Config::login, Config::password, "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = 'TCP')(HOST = my.host.cz')(PORT = '1510'))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = 'mySid')))");
```

but I get errors:

> ORA-12163: TNS:connect descriptor is too long

or

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

I don't know how to execute tnsping from my computer, but somebody else tried it from his one using my connect descriptor, and it was OK.

Maybe I'm not including correct libraries.

I'm using [OCCI version 12.2.0.1.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html), Basic Package and *SDK Package* downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html).

**Can anyone tell me what am I missing and how can I create the connection?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using OCCI version 12 and trying to connect to the server of version 11.
Downloading OCCI version 11 helped.